# Android : How to post data to a mysql server using json /php webservice

Tags: android, json, performance, web-services, android-intent

Hello I am a beginner in this feild. I know how to fetch the data from a db but i dont know how to post data to database on a webserve.

I am unable to figureout the problem of posting data to a webserver.

- Could you guys plz suggest me a code for a signup page / report bugs etc. pages. By checking out that code i ll be able to understand the logic.
- The theory of how to deal with post and get in json parsing.

This is the class which I am using for parsing:

```
public class ServiceHandler{

    static String response = null;
    public final static int GET = 1;
    public final static int POST = 2;

    public ServiceHandler() {

    }
    public String makeServiceCall(String url, int method) {
        return this.makeServiceCall(url, method, null);
    }

    public String makeServiceCall(String url, int method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {
        try {
            // http client
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
            HttpResponse httpResponse = null;

            // Checking http request method type
            if (method == POST) {
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                // adding post params
                if (params != null) {
                    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
                }

                httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

            } else if (method == GET) {
                // appending params to url
                if (params != null) {
                    String paramString = URLEncodedUtils
                            .format(params, "utf-8");
                    url += "?" + paramString;
                }
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

            }
            httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return response;

    }
}
```

Comment: which service r u using to post data?php?.net??

Comment: i am testing on php localhost

Comment: what extactly u wanna post and can u post the php script here?

Comment: i am usign it to make a report bugs form.

Comment: ok but wha is paramters? what u want as rsponse from php etc??